# Why is some of the text not showing ( Bootstrap )

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm still new to web development and bootstrap, and I have a small question. In  under header, "The First" isn't showing for some reason. I tried overflow wrap and everything yet nothing is working. Is it related to bootstrap or related to my code? Thank you guys, and sorry for the disturbance. Here is the link for the codepen because it wont show here.

https://codepen.io/hnaboulsi/project/editor/XgeQap

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Syne Mono', monospace;
  color: black;
  size: 0.5rem;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(237, 104, 104);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(237, 104, 104, 1) position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-color {
  background: rgb(237, 104, 104);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(237, 104, 104, 1) 0%, rgba(232, 118, 118, 1) 50%, rgba(236, 159, 159, 1) 100%);
}

.nav-link {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-color bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!--Header-->
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>The First lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem loerem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="/images/Online shopping _Outline.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @isherwood How to do that? I'm using bootstrap so I don't think I can change it. Can I override it and do that?

Comment: You have an <h1> open and </h2> closing tag.

Comment: Okay, so I added body{ padding-top 3%} but the thing is that it makes the page longer than it should be. I get the scrolling thing on the right when I do that. Sorry for any disturbance @isherwood and thank you for helping me.

Comment: I did, but the solutions have body in them, thats why. @isherwood

Comment: Thats not it @RyanThomas. Thank you though for trying to help me.

Comment: I did header{padding-top: 4%;} Thank you so much isherwood for your help, and sorry for the duplicate question.